# Why is paging used?

Tags: memory, pagefile, ramdisk, paging

Paging is a form of primary memory management, said to be a way to store data non-contiguously.

It's achieved by setting a chunk, or page, size, so pages can be allocated in different areas. Would there then be some form of page table / database, to locate programs/data etc?

Why do pages need to be used, if there's already a chunk size (1bit)?

Does it make it easier?
I'm missing something.

Comment: Having a table of every bit that is available would be kind of memory intensive and slow. Hence you use a bigger chunk. There is [page table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_table) for this.

Comment: The distinction between virtual memory paging, and paging in RAM isn't very clear; is there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "paging" normally refers to the process of moving data between physical memory and secondary storage as part of virtual memory.

> Why is paging used?

You appear to be using the term to describe the process of creating a logical address space using pages. This is done for many reasons:

- To support virtual memory
- To provide separate address spaces for processes
- Makes memory management easier
- Allows data sharing when desired

> Would there then be some form of page table / database, to locate programs/data etc?

The logical address space composed of pages is defined by one or more page tables.

> Why do pages need to be used, if there's already a chunk size (1bit)?

It would be extremely inefficient to allocate memory in bits.