# How to delete pagefile

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-memory, pagefile

I'm using XP and I want to delete the file `pagefile.sys` 
[image]

It is covering 4GB of data and I want to delete it. I have installed treesize free software and deleted the `pagefile.sys` but after restart it come back again. I have gone to My computer > Properties > Advanced > startup and recovery > settings > write debugging information I have set to small memory dump (64KB). And also yet it show 4GB after restart. Is there any solution to delete it permanently so that I can free up the disk space?

[image]

**nO PAGING SET**

[image]

Comment: don't delete your pagefile

Comment: Removing the pagefile will have a negative impact on the performance of your system. It should also be noted that XP is now obsolete and you should consider migrating to Windows 7 or greater.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/1160535/why-is-paging-used

Comment: @Burgi but its using 4GB space unnecessary

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/14795/windows-swap-page-file-enable-or-disable also directly related. This is a bad idea

Comment: @atek more like, its using 4gb to help use your ram more efficiently. How much ram do you have?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek 4GB ram to my pc

Comment: and is it set to size your page file automatically as is the default? WIndows XP wouldn't be able to use 4gb anyway (it tops out at 3.5gb on 32 bit) and it feels like someone set a static size. There's better ways to solve this.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek i have mention above in my question i have set that 64kb, delete the pagefile and restart but its not showing 64bk always 4GB

Comment: Memory dump != pagefile. While your memory dump goes into the page file, your pagefile gets used for ... well, paging in most cases

Comment: @JourneymanGeek is there any other way to set size lower for example 100mb other than 4GB

Comment: 13nilux's answer seems correct. Other than that you really ought not to do this, and should set it to system managed size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer assumes you know and accept the consequences of deleting the page file.

You can disable it by doing the following:

1. Open the System Properties window
2. Navigate to the "Advanced" tab.
3. On the "Performance" section, choose the "Setting" button.
4. On the "Performance Options" dialog box that opens, navigate to the "Advanced" tab.
5. On the "Virtual Memory" section, click on "Change". It will open "Virtual Memory" window.
6. Uncheck the option "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives"
7. Select the drive where pagefile.sys file is situated.
8. Select "No paging file" and click on "Set".
9. Click on "OK".
10. Restart your computer so that the change could take effect.

This will delete the pagefile.sys system file.

You might also consider leaving it at `System Managed` state, as suggested by Journeyman Geek♦:

[image: see here]

Comment: There is no virtual memory group. Note I have ask for xp not for win 7 or win8. I have attach the image

Comment: Click on `Settings` under `Performance` ..

Comment: I believe in Windows XP a restart is required for the setting to be effective.

Comment: My answer *effectly* covers the same ground as yours - other than that I recommend leaving it at system managed. If you wish, feel free to use my screenshot of the systems properties and other windows in any way you see fit https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6Oep.png I've confirmed this works on an XP vm

Comment: @13nilux after following the steps and restart still the same 4GB is back

Comment: @atek you're doing something wrong, follow the steps exactly as described. You should be logged in with Administrator account (or account member of the Administrators group, having admin privileges). Restart your computer and it will work.

Comment: @13nilux I have attach a new screenshot with no paging set

Comment: Did you do step 6 - Uncheck the option "Automatically manage paging file size for all drives"? - not just for C:, but for D: too?